# Azure AD OAuth Token Claim - Populate DisplayName attribute for Application Users

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-application-settings

When I request an OAuth token from Azure AD for an application user (using a client_id and client_secret) targeting the correct resource audience (target application), I don't know how to get Azure AD to populate a claim for the client's **DisplayName** attribute (primarily for an application client, but also users should work too) in Azure AD.

```
POST /<tenant_id>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&resource=<target_aud_app_uri>&client_secret=<client_secret>
```

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "xxx",
  "kid": "xxx"
}.{
  "aud": "<target_aud_app_uri>",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_id>/",
  "iat": 1619676176,
  "nbf": 1619676176,
  "exp": 1619680076,
  "aio": "xxx",
  "appid": "<client_id>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_id>/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "xxx",
  "rh": "xxx",
  "roles": [
    "XXX"
  ],
  "sid": "xxx",
  "sub": "xxx",
  "tenant_ctry": "AU",
  "tenant_region_scope": "OC",
  "tid": "xxx",
  "uti": "xxx",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

In the target application configuration in Azure AD, I've added all the optional claims it allows in the UI, and even tried adding 'display_name' via the manifest but it doesn't know how to pick it up. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Azure Portal Azure AD Application Token configuration screenshot]

Comment: This is possible under the `Microosft.graph` namespace only cannot be used for any custom app.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread, thanks！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50421) has been asked before.

This is possible under the `Microosft.graph` namespace only cannot be used for any custom app. In other words, only the ms graph api token has `app_displayname` claim. For the token of the application custom api, it is currently not possible to add the `app_displayname` claim, at least for now this is impossible.

I suggest you submit [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory), and I will vote for it.

Comment: I have created a UserVoice for this:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/43337229-optionally-populate-all-azure-ad-attributes-in-oau